# advice on working on remote asp.net applications

Tags: asp.net, remote-access

I'm a (relatively new) developer using asp.net with VB.NET. Currently all my applications are developed on my PC and then are built and moved onto the web server. I'm going to be working remotely for 3 months in which time I'll be connecting to the company network via VPN. What is the best way to access my projects? I need to have the projects stored on the company network so that others can access them too. So simply copying the projects to my laptop, working on them, then copying them back won't suffice. I tried to just open the projects off of the network share but am getting application trust problems.

I'm just wondering what other developers do in this situation?

Answer (score 2):

You will need some kind of source control solution, probably best if it was web based. Something like [git](http://github.com/) which is very popular maybe useful for you.

Comment: thanks had a look and it seems pretty good. We have free access to visual studio team system which seems to have a lot of the same features. you have any experience with that?

Comment: That will do the job - I havent worked with it remotely so im not sure what the web hooks are like - unless vpn is an option for you.

Comment: They just announced something called Visual Studio® Team Explorer Everywhere 2010 which sounds like what you need

Answer (score 0):

WinMerge is pretty simple to use.